# Python Socket: infinite loop socket bind, listen will cause memory flood or not?

Tags: python, loops

```
import socket
import sys
import binascii
import datetime
import time

try:
    port = 2122
    host = ''

except IndexError:
    print ("Error: ")
    print ("Be sure to specify username, password, port, database name and table name.\n")
    print ("Syntax: ./script.py username password port db_name table_name.")
    print ("Example: ./script.py hank mypass 8762 testdb test_table")
    print ("\nExit...")
    sys.exit(1)

while 1:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(5)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print ('Connected by', addr)
    data = c.recv(1042)
    s=binascii.hexlify(data)
    print(s)
    data = None
    c.close() 
    time.sleep(1)   
print('Exited!')
```

above are my coding in a infinity loop to keep listening client side,
waiting client side to send the data and print it. that's all.
this writing method will cause memory flood or not? because of keep opening socket and close with infinity loop!.

P/S:i have tried once bind and listen socket,only loop with .recv, but it doesn't working.only can received data once.

Comment: How do you expect `IndexError` to be raised there?

Comment: No,this code work properly,i just worry about the memory flooding problem,cause keep bind and listening the socket.

Comment: Why are you closing the connection after receiving data?  If you are expecting multiple clients to connect, you should be spawning a new process to handle each connection (the `accept`/`fork`) model, or you should be using a `select()` or `poll()` loop to multiplex the i/o in a single process.  These are both basic designs for which there are lots of good examples available online.

Comment: +1 to @larsks. Put more simply: What are you actually trying to do, at a higher level?

Answer (score 1):

If by "memory flooding" you mean "memory leak", then no, there are no memory leaks here.

Each time through the loop, once you reassign both `s` and `c`, you have no other references to the previous values, so they will be garbage collected. In CPython, this should happen right away; in other implementations (PyPy, Jython, IronPython), it will happen at some unpredictable point.

However, you could potentially have a problem with file handles. That "some unpredictable point" is driven by your need to clean up memory. If you have other resources that need to be cleaned up more aggressively than memory, you can't rely on the GC to do it for you. And sockets (file handles) are exactly such a kind of resource. You don't want to have 25000 sockets lying around unused, that the GC hasn't touched because they're only using 500KB of memory.

You are explicitly calling `c.close()` each time through the loop; you should do the same for `s`. Or, better, use a `with:` block.

All that being said, this is a very strange design; just because it doesn't leak memory doesn't mean it's something you'd actually want to do.